# Can we set dynamically the Command TimeOut by on query execution time in entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

Can we set dynamically the Command TimeOut is "Time of the query execution" in entity framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way:

```
using (var context = new EntityContext())
{
    context.Database.CommandTimeout = 300;
}
```

**EDIT: Answer comment**

> Based on CURD statements, I want set Timeout Limit

I'm not sure which EF version you are using since you flagged EF6, EF5 and EF4.

I will assume in my answer EF6

You can use DbCommandInterceptor: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/database-command-interception.aspx

To check the `CommandText` and set the `CommandTimeout` based on it.

Comment: Thanks above one, It's working for increasing of execution timeout of query.  In this case we have to added every time before execution of SP/Statement. or be for creation of Instances to repository, I'm looking ... Can we set the command Timeout based on Query Execution time (How long query will execute)

Comment: I don't understand your question Chandra

Comment: Let me explain my issue. We have functionality like valid customers with DB, While validation process, we are checking customer data... If customer data have any new details we have to update in DB. In this process we have do few CURD operations on customer tables, While this process we are getting Timeout ..  It's not happening frequently only if customers are having more numbers new values .... After few discussion with BA... But there are not happy to touch functionality... My Question is "By any cost this customer Update need to complete", Based on CURD statements, I want set Timeout Limit

Comment: Thanks for you response,  Currently we are using EF6, But initially we start with EF4.0.

**Database Command Insterception** , It will work for Store Procedure?

Comment: Yes Chandra, CommandInterception should work every any command created from Entity Framework included Stored Procedure

Comment: Thanks for Info, I will let you know after trail on this CommandInterception.